# The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address. when sending an email

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, html-email, mailmessage

Trying to send email to multiple recipient using below code gives me this error:

> The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail
>   address.

```
string[] email = {"emailone@gmail.com","emailtow@gmail.com"};
using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("teset123321@gmail.com", email.ToString()))
{
     try
     {
          mm.Subject = "sub;
          mm.Body = "msg";
          mm.Body += GetGridviewData(GridView1);
          mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
          SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
          smtp.Host = "smtpout.server.net";
          smtp.EnableSsl = false;
          NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("email", "pass");
          smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
          smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
          smtp.Port = 80;
          smtp.Send(mm);
          ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email sent.');", true);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Response.Write("Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message);    
      }
}
```

Comment: new NetworkCredential("email@mymail.com", "pass");

Comment: Before asking a question, make sure you've thoroughly debugged your program by stepping through the code and trying to spot what the problem might be. And when you posted a question, make sure you specify exactly which line your error is coming from

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your using line to this:

```
using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage())
```

Add the from address:

```
mm.From = new MailAddress("myaddress@gmail.com");
```

You can loop through your string array of e-mail addresses and add them one by one like this:

```
string[] email = { "emailone@gmail.com", "emailtwo@gmail.com", "emailthree@gmail.com" };

foreach (string address in email)
{
    mm.To.Add(address);
}
```

Example:

```
string[] email = { "emailone@gmail.com", "emailtwo@gmail.com", "emailthree@gmail.com" };

using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage())
{
    try
    {
        mm.From = new MailAddress("myaddress@gmail.com");

        foreach (string address in email)
        {
            mm.To.Add(address);
        }

        mm.Subject = "sub;
        // Other Properties Here
    }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Response.Write("Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Presently your code:

```
new NetworkCredential("email", "pass");
```

treats `"email"` as an email address which eventually is not an email address rather a string array which contains the email address.

So you can try like this:

```
foreach (string add in email)
{
    mm.To.Add(new MailAddress(add));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue while working with SMTP.js but the issues were coming from the whitespace so please try and trim it off when working with emails. I hope this helps someone.